# Autolayout - Difference between setting width for frame and width as a constraint

Tags: ios, autolayout

Can someone give a detailed explanation of the differences between setting width in the view frame vs setting a width constraint?

What happens if they're different?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The auto-layout engine works by changing views' `frame`s.

If they're different, the value specified by the constraint will change the frame at layout time. To put it simply, the constraint wins and the frame's width is ignored.

Your storyboard will show you a "Misplaced Views" warning. (See [Resolving Auto Layout Issues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ResolvingIssues/ResolvingIssues.html) for more examples.)

Comment: I'm trying to understand this fully. I changed the frame width in storyboard of my textfield to 1. No width constraint, but proper spacing constraints all around. XCode gives a yellow layout warning but of course the textfield displays at a usable width due to other constraints... So is it correct to say that the frame values set in IB are meaningless at runtime? They're just there to give the developer an idea of the layout in IB?

Comment: Or rather, at runtime the frame WILL initially be set but then constraints will then alter that frame?

Comment: Right. Basically, ignore the frames, and make it look how you want using constraints.